# ASP.NET MVC: action methods with one param not named ID and non-integer

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, asp.net-mvc-routing

Consider an ASP.NET MVC 1.0 project using the Areas convention as described on this [Nov. 2008 Phil Haack blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/04/areas-in-aspnetmvc.aspx). This solution works great once it's set up!

My trouble is starting thanks to my limited knowledge of ASP.NET MVC's routing rules.

My intention is to create an action method and URL structure like this:

> `http://mysite/Animals/Dogs/ViewDog/Buster`

`DogsController.ViewDog()` looks like this:

```
public ActionResult ViewDog(string dogName)
{
     if (dogName!= null)
     {
         var someDog = new DogFormViewModel(dogName); //snip a bunch more

         return View(someDog);
     }
     else { return View("DogNotFound"); }           
}
```

The task at hand is ensuring that the `RegisterRoutes()` has the correct entries.

**UPDATE**

Here's the new route being mapped:

```
routes.MapRoute("ViewDog", "Animals/{controller}/{action}/{dogName}",
                                     new { controller = "Dogs", 
                                           action = "ViewDog", dogName = "" });
```

The link to the URL is created:

`<%= Html.RouteLink("Brown Buster", "ViewDog", new RouteValueDictionary(new { controller="Dogs", action="ViewDog", dogName="Buster" }))%>`

The URL is created as expected. Thanks to [Craig Stuntz and his blog post on `Html.RouteLink`](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/).

> `http://mySite/Animals/Dogs/ViewDog/Buster`

**New Problem:** The param `dogName` doesn't pickup the string value "Buster" from the URL. The call to the method succeeds, but the argument evaluates to null.

**Questions**

How can you:

- make this route work with a string, and remove the default convention `int id` in the route? **I'd like to change the name of the parameter away from `int`.**

Comment: The default is id, not int id. Route tokens are untyped.

Comment: What order are your routes defined in?  Is this Route after the default route with 'id' in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that ActionLink is actually matching the route you show them the question? When you have more than one route, I strongly recommend using RouteLink instead of ActionLink, [as I explain in great detail in this post](http://blogs.teamb.com/craigstuntz/2009/03/18/38085/). When you use RouteLink, there is no possibility that you will match the wrong route, at least in URL generation.

Comment: Thanks Craig. Appreciate the suggestion. I've used it, but a new problem exists now, where the argument passed to the method is null, even though I've explicitly sent it in the RouteLink. Any suggestions?

Comment: Now you're matching the wrong route on the way *in.* Get Phil Haack's routing debugger to see which route you're matching. It's not the one you want.

Answer (score 0):

The default parameter "id" doesn't have to be an int. It'll match whatever type you declare in your action method. Why not just do the following?

```
public ActionResult ViewDog(string id)
{
     if (id!= null)
     {
         var someDog = new DogFormViewModel(id); //snip a bunch more

         return View(someDog);
     }
     else { return View("DogNotFound"); }           
}
```